# Unable to access databases created with hive and run queries on hue

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I would like to use Hue as a visualization interface for hive, the server hiveserver 2 starts well and I can work in command without problem.

My hadoop is also functional (single node running on localhost), I managed to configure the hdfs files for hue and I can easily view hdfs files with the interface hue. but my big problem for weeks is to make a HIVE request with hue (even if I configured according to the research I found on the internet). I can not do it and get stuck on it

your help will be really appreciated.

this is hive-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<configuration>


-<property>

<name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>

<value>/tmp/hive_temp</value>

<description>Local scratch space for Hive jobs</description>

</property>


-<property>

<name>hive.execution.engine</name>

<value>mr</value>

<description> Expects one of [mr, tez, spark]. Chooses execution engine. Options are: mr (Map reduce, default)</description>

</property>


-<property>

<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>

<value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false</value>

<description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>

</property>


-<property>

<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>

<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>

<description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>

</property>


-<property>

<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>

<value>hive</value>

<description>Username to use against metastore database</description>

</property>


-<property>

<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>

<value>hivepassword</value>

<description>password to use against metastore database</description>

</property>


-<property>

<name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>

<value>/tmp/hive_tmp</value>

<description>HDFS root scratch dir for Hive jobs which gets created with write all (733) permission</description>

</property>


-<property>

<name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>

<value>/user/hive/warehouse</value>

<description>HDFS root scratch dir for Hive jobs which gets created with write all (733) permission</description>

</property>

</configuration>
```

and hive configuration in HUE pseudo-distributed.ini

```
 # Host where HiveServer2 is running.
  # If Kerberos security is enabled, use fully-qualified domain name (FQDN).
   hive_server_host=localhost

  # Port where HiveServer2 Thrift server runs on.
  hive_server_port=10002

  # Hive configuration directory, where hive-site.xml is located
  hive_conf_dir=/usr/local/hive/conf
```

Comment: Hive is typically port 10000. Hue doesn't work with Hive 2 or 3, AFAIK

Comment: @cricket_007 ca run in port 1000,10001,10002 and actually it runs on port 10002 in my laptop but i have not seen anywhere that hue does not support Hive2 ou

Comment: Hue supports **HiveServer2**, but Hive 1.x runs that. I meant, if you have just downloded Hive, it would be version 2.x, or 3.x... For example, if you install Cloudera CDH, Hue would be configured with Impala and Hive 1.x, I believe